# ruby rails, bootstrap link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, link-to

I am using Rails 4 with the adminlte-rails gem. Even though 'dashboard' is a valid route, it will only let me link to it using regular  instead of link_to. Every time I use link_to, the section with dashboard disappears. The code below shows the working example for dashboard. Below that, is a working link_to for the managestudents_path.  I am not sure why one works and the other hides the Dashboard.

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
   <li class="active">
     <a href="/dashboard">
       <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
     </a>
   </li>
   <!-- Manage Users -->
   <li class="treeview">
     <a href="#">
       <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Manage Users</span>
       <i class="fa fa-angle-right pull-right"></i>
      </a>
         <ul class="treeview-menu">
          <li>
            <%= link_to managestudents_path, type: "button", data: {toggle: "expanding"} do %>
               <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i> Students
            <% end %>
         </li>
```

Here are some of the link_to I've tried, but don't work for dashboard.

```
 <li class="active">
   <% link_to dashboard_path  do%>
       <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
   <% end %>
 </li>
```

and with no span

```
<% link_to dashboard_path  do%>
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `=`:

```
<%= link_to dashboard_path  do%>
   <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I forgot the "=". Thank you! Now working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because once you wrote `<% link_to` and the other one `<%= link_to`